# Rails 2 submit buttons using I18n returning different behaviour

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

The following is the rendered HTML

```
<form action="/transactions" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="9aQsBj/W7l32NzqVc4juxiq2oeU0dQiOTlzWtKaaBm6WzQkfZFX2PU21KuOKZ+nJ8YZGPJzj593ERe9FVFB9GA==">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="cell small-4">
      <input value="15275" type="hidden" name="transaction[consumer_id]" id="transaction_consumer_id">
      Total<br>
      <strong>21.57&nbsp;€</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-4 text-center">
        <input value="21.57" type="hidden" name="transaction[full_amount]" id="transaction_full_amount">
    </div>
      <div class="cell small-4 text-center">
          Coupon
          ≤ 2
          <input value="0" min="0" max="2" step="1" type="number" name="transaction[coupons]" id="transaction_coupons">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="cell small-4 flex_end">
      <input type="submit" name="transaction" value="buy" class="button success" style="padding: 6px 16px; border-radius: 8px;" data-confirm="Confirm buy" data-disable-with="buy">
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-4 text-right flex_end">
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-4 text-right flex_end">
        <input type="submit" name="gift_card" value="Use gift card" class="button" style="padding: 6px 16px; border-radius: 8px;" data-confirm="Confirm buy with gift card" data-disable-with="Use gift card">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The submit buttons are generated by the following code

```
<%= form_with(model: Transaction.new, url: transactions_path, method: :post, local: false) do |f| %>
[...]
  <div class='grid-x grid-padding-x'>
    <div class='cell small-4 flex_end'>
      <%= f.submit t('transaction.purchase'), name: 'transaction', class: 'button success', style: 'padding: 6px 16px; border-radius: 8px;', data: { confirm: t('transaction.payment_confirm') } %>
    </div>
    <div class='cell small-4 text-right flex_end'>
    </div>
    <div class='cell small-4 text-right flex_end'>
      <% if @gift_card_balance.to_d > 0 %>
        <input value="29.26" type="hidden" name="transaction[gift_card_max]" id="transaction_gift_card_max">
        <%= f.submit t('transaction.gift_card_use'), name: 'gift_card', class: 'button', style: 'padding: 6px 16px; border-radius: 8px;', data: { confirm: t('transaction.gift_card_payment_confirm') } %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The latter button processes all the parameters and is executed as expected.
`Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "transaction"=>{ "consumer_id"=>"15275", "full_amount"=>"21.57", "coupons"=>"2", "gift_card_max"=>"29.26"}, "gift_card"=>"Use gift card"}`

But the first button ignores the transaction parameters
`Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "transaction"=>"buy"}`

How should these submit buttons be set so that they both send the parameters, in addition to the submit param?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= button_tag name: 'submit', class: 'button success', style: 'padding: 6px 16px; border-radius: 8px;', data: { confirm: t('transaction.payment_confirm') } do %>
  <%= t('transaction.purchase') %>
<% end %>
```

renders

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="button success" style="padding: 6px 16px; border-radius: 8px;" data-confirm="Confirm purchase">
         purchase
</button>
```

and thus processes the parameters as expected:

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "transaction"=>{"consumer_id"=>"15275", "full_amount"=>"21.57", "coupons"=>"0", "gift_card_max"=>"29.26"}, "submit"=>""}
```

**without having changed the other button**

So the `name` must be consistent & the `value` change.
But for i18n, the `submit` tag will not cut it *nicely* as the controller logic would have to deal with the various locale cases for the different value.
The `button_tag` allows to succinctly handle the other case based on the name of the button, i.e.

```
if params[:gift_card]
```